# How to add HTML Tags in NSMutableArray in objective c

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to add HTML content in NSMutableArray in UITableView.

I am using code like this

```
 namearray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    namearray=[responsedict valueForKey:@"News"];

  NSMutableArray *trimmedStrings = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSString *string in namearray) {
            NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<p></p>&amp;#39;"];
            NSString *trimmedString = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
            [trimmedStrings addObject:trimmedString];
        }
        namearray = trimmedStrings;
```

But this code remove tag not adding HTML content.I am getting value in array like this `"<p>&quot;I don&#39;t want to live in a lie anymore. When I was 10, my mother in a hotel in Athens, Greece.</p>"`

My cell for row AtIndexpath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *STI=@"STI";
    NewsTableViewCell *cell = (NewsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:STI];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    NSString *strImgURLAsString = [NewsImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [strImgURLAsString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strImgURLAsString];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imgURL] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (!connectionError) {
            img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            if (img==nil) {
                img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"userimage.png"];
            }
            cell.newsimage.image=img;

            // pass the img to your imageview
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@",connectionError);
        }
    }];

    cell.Headlbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[headarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.bodylbl.attributedText=attrStrBody;


    cell.bodylbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.bodylbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.bodylbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16]];
 //   cell.randrid.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;

}
```

How to solve this issue.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Couldn't understand your problem.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore From Web Service I am getting some text in the HTML format like <p></p> for that In using code as in the question. But the problem I am facing is the text is not showing in correct HTML format.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I am getting value in array like this "<p>&quot;I don&#39;t want to live in a lie anymore. When I was 10, my mother in a hotel in Athens, Greece.</p>".

Comment: Why dont you use attributed string with option [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType] to parse HTML content?

Comment: @Swift_Guru Can I add it in NSMutableArray??

Comment: @Swift_Guru Can you share code how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *aux = [webServiceArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[aux dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSFontAttributeName:font} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];`
```

set font which you want to set in font attribute

Comment: How to add this atteStr in NSMutableArray?

Comment: No need to add in array. just set this attrStr wherever you want i.e.lbl.attributedtext = attrStr

Comment: Done Bro Thank you.

Comment: It is displaying Only one text in table view . I don't have string I have Array and I need to show it into table view.

Comment: Show me your array.

Comment: My Array is like this <__NSArrayI 0x7fadb2801900>(
,
Helpline Numbers,
Core Values,
Employee Safety Pledge ,
Hand tool Safety 
)

Comment: and what you want in 1st row--Helpline Num , 2nd row - core values ??

Comment: All  thats why I am using TableView.

Comment: Yes That has no problem problem is in  cell.bodylbl.attributedText Hear I am getting HTML Tags value.

Comment: what is attrStrBody?

Comment: NSAttributedString * attrStrBody;

Comment: first get string from array with perticular indexpath and then use above solution which i provided.try it

Comment: Array is from web service Its dynamic. How to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134953/discussion-between-swift-guru-and-muju).

Comment: Done Thanks a lot bro once again.